# Dynamic naming using savefig

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, savefig

I have a df with some number of columns, and I'm creating bivariate plots using a loop like so:

```
for col in df.columns[2:len(df.columns)]:
    sns.factorplot(x='xvar', y=col,  data=df)
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)

    plt.show()
    plt.clf()

plt.close()
```

Instead of displaying all the plots I'd like to save them with the naming convention [xaxis]_y[axis].png. However, I'm not sure how to pass more than 1 item through plt.savefig() where one of the items will change every time.
I've seen a few answers that rely on lists ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682628/use-savefig-in-python-with-string-and-iterative-index-in-the-name), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46418007/matplotlib-savefig-over-multiple-graphs-keeps-saving-the-same-graph)), but I'm hoping there's a way to achieve the same results without having to create lists to pass through.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by using lists.  Regardless, you need to provide a filename for your plot.  I assume your column names are strings, so this could be something as simple as plt.savefig(col + ".png").  What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
plt.savefig('var1' + '_' + col' + '.png')
```

Achieved the desired result

Answer (score 4):

Since `python 3.6` you can use [`f-strings`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) to format strings dynamically:

```
for col in df.columns[2:]:
    sns.factorplot(x='xvar', y=col, data=df)
    sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
    plt.savefig(f'xvar_{col}.png')
```